# How do I catch a thief without killing him?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In previous games, when I chased a thief across the rooftops with no weapon but my fists equipped, I could sprint after him with `RT` (playing on Xbox 360) and when I got close enough, `B` would turn into `Tackle`. That enabled me to tackle the thief and take my money back (or re-steal whoever's money he'd already stolen) without killing him. It seems I don't have the `Tackle` option in Revelations. So is there a way for me to get the thief without killing him?

I tried just beating him up once I managed to catch up to him, but since thieves always run around on precarious rooftops, I punched him off a roof by accident and he died anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this is part of the ["Tax Evasion" achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/achievement.aspx?achievementid=157173), so searching for videos about that achievement might help.  I found one where someone grabbed the tax collector, but there's also talk that it's possible to "hook sweep" with <kbd>B</kbd> if you've got your hookblade equipped (the tutorial message for this pops up conveniently as this guy's grabbing the tax collector):

I'm guessing that "hook sweep" replaced the "tackle" move from earlier AC games.

Comment: Yep, it's the new replacement.  Alternatively you could do the hook-and-throw on enemies.  Though, you don't need to equip your hookblade, it does it automatically.